# Google Maps Autocomplete error Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, autocomplete

this line gives me error "use of unresolved identifier 'URL'"

```
let url = URL(string: urlpath!)
```

Comment: Try this NSURL(string: "")

Comment: thanks worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are swift ver is 3 then use

```
let url = URL(string: urlpath!)
```

else it is lesser than swift3 then Use NSURL instead of URL

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 2.2 , this is the correct way:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
```